# Add a button in full screen mode to reset to normal mode in two plots in a shiny app

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

In the app below I display 2 plots and each time I press the relative `actionButton()` I get them in full screen. In full screen mode a second `actionButton()` is displayed to escape the full screen and then it is hidden again. But I cannot make it work for 2 plots instead of one based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238869/add-a-button-in-full-screen-mode-to-reset-to-normal-mode-in-a-shiny-app).

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

js <- "
function openFullscreen(elem, plotselector) {
  $('#exitbtn').show();
  $(plotselector).addClass('fullscreen');
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
function exitFullscreen() {
  $('#exitbtn').hide();
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
function openFullscreen(elem, plotselector) {
  $('#exitbtn2').show();
  $(plotselector).addClass('fullscreen2');
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
function exitFullscreen() {
  $('#exitbtn2').hide();
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
"

css <- "
#exitbtn {
  display: none;
}
.fullscreen {
  height: 90% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
#exitbtn2 {
  display: none;
}
.fullscreen2 {
  height: 90% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 3,
      actionButton(
        "fs", "Full screen", 
        onclick = "openFullscreen(document.getElementById('frame'), '#ggplot');"
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 9,
      div(
        id = "frame", 
        plotOutput("ggplot"),
        actionButton(
          "exitbtn", "Exit",
          onclick = "exitFullscreen(); $('#ggplot').removeClass('fullscreen');"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 3,
      actionButton(
        "fs2", "Full screen", 
        onclick = "openFullscreen(document.getElementById('frame'), '#ggplot2');"
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 9,
      div(
        id = "frame", 
        plotOutput("ggplot2"),
        actionButton(
          "exitbtn2", "Exit",
          onclick = "exitFullscreen(); $('#ggplot2').removeClass('fullscreen');"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
  })
  output[["ggplot2"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't define JavaScript functions with the same names. Also don't use duplicated ids in HTML.

```
js <- "
function openFullscreen(elem, plotselector) {
  $(plotselector).addClass('fullscreen');
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
function exitFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}"

  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 3,
      actionButton(
        "fs", "Full screen", 
        onclick = "$('#exitbtn').show(); openFullscreen(document.getElementById('frame'), '#ggplot');"
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 9,
      div(
        id = "frame", 
        plotOutput("ggplot"),
        actionButton(
          "exitbtn", "Exit",
          onclick = "exitFullscreen(); $('#ggplot').removeClass('fullscreen'); $(this).hide();"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 3,
      actionButton(
        "fs2", "Full screen", 
        onclick = "$('#exitbtn2').show(); openFullscreen(document.getElementById('frame2'), '#ggplot2');"
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 9,
      div(
        id = "frame2", 
        plotOutput("ggplot2"),
        actionButton(
          "exitbtn2", "Exit",
          onclick = "exitFullscreen(); $('#ggplot2').removeClass('fullscreen'); $(this).hide();"
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

The CSS class `fullscreen2` is not needed.

Comment: can u provide it as full answer?

Comment: I dont know why but it does not work only when I intergaret this code chunk above in the shiny app.

Comment: @firmo23 What is the problem you get? I see I forgot to add `$(this).hide()` to hide the exit buttons, is it the issue?